# How do the secondary stats scale?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

As described in [wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Stats), the primary stats have an influence on the secondary stats.

But how do they scale? For 1 point gained on a primary stat, how many points do I gain in linked secondary stats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wiki has now been updated to show the [interaction between Primary and Secondary stats](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Stats#Interaction_between_Primary_and_Secondary_stats), and based on the testing by users in the official forum the currently expected values are:

#### Burliness

- +1 *HP* per level
- +1 *Melee Power* every three levels (with a 5 level deduction).

#### Sagacity

- +2 *MP* per level
- +1 *Magic Power* every two levels.

#### Nimbleness

- +1 *Dodge Chance* every two levels
- +1 *Sneakiness* every two levels.

#### Caddishness

- +1 *HP* per level
- +1 *Critical Chance* every two levels
- +1 *Haywire Chance* every two levels
- +1 *Sneakiness* every three levels.

#### Savvy

- +1 *Counter Chance* every two levels
- +1 *Sneakiness* every two levels.

#### Stubbornness

- +1 *Block Change* every three levels
- +1 *Magic Resistance* every two levels.